# Send results to multiple recipients based on value in form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a form that will submit the form results to different addresses based on form input. I know that Cognito supports this for a single drop-down selection, but I am wondering if it also supports it for checkboxes - sending emails to individuals based on which items are selected.

Example:
Let's say I have checkboxes for Sales, Support, and Employment. A person might check any single one of those, but they might also select a combination or all of them.

Does Cognito support sending an email to different contacts associated with each of those as well as supporting the ability for a site visitor to select more than one and have emails go to all appropriate parties?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Cognito Forms does support email routing based on user input of virtually any field.

The field and type determine what compare operations you can use within a calculation. A choice field of type checkboxes essentially is a list of text values, so you would be able to set a calculation to look within that list for a specific value or values to determine when to send the notification. The values you are looking for will need to match exactly with the checkbox choices, and are case-sensitive.

For example, if you have a Choice field called "Department", set to type of Checkboxes. You would want to create a notification and set the "Send When Submitted" value to be "When Department Contains 'Sales'". You can set as many conditions as you need to on the notifications, to ensure the email gets to the correct recipient. I've included a screenshot that shows the various options.

[image]

You will need to be on one of our paid plans if you need to be able to send out multiple notifications.

You can read more information regarding email routing on the [Notify the right people at the right time with email routing](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/notify-the-right-people-at-the-right-time-with-email-routing) on our [blog site](http://blog.cognitoforms.com).